# Apply a custom height and width for lightning:textarea

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I want to set the height of a lightning:textarea field, Here is what I found in the Lightning Component Developing guide -

**The rows and cols HTML attributes are not supported. To apply a custom height and width for the text area, use the class attribute.** But I can't get it to work, can anyone help me with this please?

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_textarea.htm

Comment: what have you tried? please include your code, it will be easier for community members to assist you. thanks

Answer (score 6):

You'll need to add css to do this.

If you would like to set the same custom height on all `lightning:textarea` in your component, you can add:

```
.THIS textarea {
  height: 5rem;
}
```

If you want to add height to specific `lightning:textarea`, you should make a custom css class and put it on the `lightning:textarea` you would like to modify. Here's an example of that:

```
.THIS .tallTextArea textarea {
  height: 5rem;
}

<lightning:textarea label="Default Height Text Area" />
<lightning:textarea label="Tall Text Area" class="tallTextArea" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**HTML:**

```
<lightning-textarea class="textAreaBody"></lightning-textarea>
```

**CSS:**

```
.textAreaBody {
    --sds-c-textarea-sizing-min-height:175px;
}
```